# A question involving the probability generating function

Tags: probability

I'm stumped by the following exercise: The probability generating function for X is given by $g_{X}(t)$. What is the probability generating function for $X+1$ and $2X$, in terms of $g_{X}(t)$?

For the first part I think I've got an answer down although I can't say I'm 100% sure it's correct.

This is what I got: $g_{X+1}(t)=E(t^{X+1})=E(t^{X}*t)=tE(t^{X})=tg_{X}(t)$

When it comes to the probability generating function for 2X, I don't know what to do though.

I'd be grateful for any answers.

Comment: First one is correct. For the second, use that $t^{2x}=(t^2)^x$ for any $t$ and $x$.

Answer (score 2):

WLOG, consider that $X$ is a discrete random variable, which assumes values in the set $\mathcal{X}$. Using the definitions....
$$ g_{2X}(t) = \mathbb{E}[t^{2X}] = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} p(x)t^{2x} = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} p(x)(t^{2})^x = g_X(t^2).$$

In general:

$$ g_{aX+b}(t) = \mathbb{E}[t^{aX+b}] = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} p(x)t^{ax+b} = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} p(x)(t^{a})^xt^b = t^bg_X(t^a).$$

Comment: $\checkmark$, Or simply $$\begin{align}\mathsf g_{[aX+b]}(t) &=\mathsf E(t^{aX+b})\\ &=\mathsf E((t^a)^X\cdot t^b)\\&=t^b~\mathsf g_X(t^a)\end{align}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp yes, I took the longer road.